# Why is a Teradata query faster in MS-Access than SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to join a Teradata table with about 0.5 billion records and a local table with about 10,000 records. I have it working in MS Access and it takes about 15 minutes to run. I would prefer to do it in SQL Server but can't even get a join with 1 record in the local SQL table to work.

Why is MS Access able to do this, albeit slowly, whereas SQL Server chokes? What is MS Access doing differently from SQL Server?

The SQL Server query with a join that fails:

```
SELECT a.trk, a.wgt
FROM openquery(TERADATA, 'SELECT trk, wgt 
                          FROM SHIPMENT_DB.pkg') a
INNER JOIN  (Local_Tbl) b ON a.trk = b.Tracking_Number
```

A simple SQL Server query without a join that works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(TERADATA,'SELECT trk, wgt 
                         FROM SHIPMENT_DB.pkg 
                         WHERE trk = ''773423067500''')
```

Comment: Both queries are SQL Server queries. How is Access involved?

Comment: In MS-Access, I connected to the Teradata DB via an ODBC driver. I then linked the 500M Terdata table to Access and built a simple select query that joined the two tables together. It works. MS-Access must do something different than SQL Server but what? Instead of bring the entire 500M Teradata table over before joining, how does Access handle the query? I find it strange that Access can perform this task better than SQL-Server. Makes me think I am doing something wrong in SQL Server.

Comment: My guess is that Access recognizes the size of the Teradata DB and is selecting records via IN clause. I believe that there is a way to monitor what Access is sending, but don't know it offhand. As for the SQL Server side, you might get better results using a linked server, rather than openquery. It is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer, but I had a similar issue using OPENDATASOURCE. Performance was terrible, the query took hours to run. 
The solution was to ensure all colmns involved in the WHERE clause had mathcing datatypes. In my case the remote column was INT but in the query it was being passed as a varchar: ...'WHERE remote_table.ID = ''4'''...
Once I changed all values to the appropriate datatypes the query took seconds to run.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Execution Plan in SQL Server. Since it knows very little about the dataset that is going to come back from Teradata, it is making some bad assumptions.

Swapping the order of the tables in the join will help.  Using an explicit `INNER HASH JOIN` may help (once you've switched the order).